# "Take something as read" - very old meaning of read?

Tags: etymology, expressions

[Take (something) as read](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_something_as_read) is described as an idiomatic expression. But I am wondering if [*read*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/read) has its original meaning of *advise*, *interpret* here? Is there any etymological evidence for how this expression came about or do we just accept it as idiomatic?

Comment: I can imagine it could be taken as _interpret_, but I don't see how it could be taken as _advised_. It seems to mean that all parties ostensibly interpret someting the same way.

Comment: This seems a related modern usage: [ [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/read) ] 9. To receive or comprehend (a radio message, for example): I read you loud and clear. So 'take something as being the true situation / correct information'.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock The reason I'm asking is because I can't see how it could be taken as "turning written text into words in your head" which is roughly the main modern meaning of _read_. If I had to pick a single word to change it to it would be _understood_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree that does seem similar. Has the meaning of _understand_ been passed down from Old English or has it cropped up more recently than that I wonder?

Comment: I've always interpreted the phrase to mean "take it literally", "at face value".  Don't try to apply an interpretation.  Generally in an expression such as "If you take it as read, it says that..."  The implication is that one might be inclined to apply some non-literal interpretation, but the speaker is not going to do that (at this moment, at least).  It may also have some "Roberts Rules" kind of meaning.

Comment: I had never encountered this usage before. Thank you for introducing me to it. The metaphor to me appears to arise along the lines Colin Fine sketches in his answer: if it is *read*, then it *must have been written*. And, of course, *as it is written, so let it be done*. People only write (record) established results; in this (metaphorical) case, established by consensus of opinion. A related metaphor in contemporary use is "*being on the same page*".

Comment: [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=read&allowed_in_frame=0) says that the original was more like 'to advise' (from West Germanic 'reden'. BUt to take something as read is metaphorical from the modern literal meaning of 'seeing words with eyes'.

Comment: @Hot Licks The expression is a well established fixed expression / idiom, at least in British English: **take something as read** [British]:  Assume something without [perceiving] the need for further discussion:
_you can take it as read that you have the contract_ [ [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/take-something-as-read) ]

Answer (score 11):

If you find the phrase in the OED, (meaning P9 under 'read'), the earliest examples given are:

> (1811) "Petitions.., all of which were taken as read, and ordered to lie on the table."
>
> (1863) "Gentlemen, I presume that..we may regard the report of the directors to be taken as read."

In both of these the phrase is literal: assume, or pretend, that the documents in question have actually been read. I am sure that this is the origin of the more metaphorical expression.

Comment: Josh61's answer makes more sense in this context.

Answer (score 7):

According to the Word Detective the origin is from parliamentary bureaucratic  procedures and the meaning is just literal.

***[Take it as read](http://www.word-detective.com/2008/08/take-it-as-read/):***

> - The Oxford English Dictionary defines ***“to take something as read”*** as “to treat (a statement, a subject, etc.) as if it has been agreed, without having a discussion about it; to take for granted.” *The phrase, which dates back to the late 19th century, most often seems to be used to mean “to accept something as a given or as having already been stated and heard, in order to move on to other things”* (“‘It’s really I who ought to say ‘sorry,’ you know. … ‘We’ll take it all as read,’ put in Miss Wilson hastily,” 1930). “Take it as read” is a way to fast-forward past a discussion that would be pointless, painful or redundant.
> - ***The roots of “take it as read” lie in parliamentary procedure, the conduct of meetings governed by Robert’s Rules of Order and the like***. *It is common, for instance, for members of a group to accept the minutes of previous meetings “as read,” meaning without objection, or to approve a resolution as presented (“read”) to the group without modification or the debate that would ensue.*
> - The minutes of nearly every organization under the sun, to judge from a Google search, are riddled with the phrase “accepted as read” (“Dr. Fister moved that the August 4, 2006 minutes be accepted as read. Ms. LaVallee seconded the motion, and it passed unanimously,” Board of Dental Examiners, Augusta, Maine, 2006). In the slightly less formal form “take it as read,” the phrase then became a popular way to move a conversation swiftly past a bump in the road.

Answer (score 2):

I am reasonably certain (though without written authority) that the origin of the phrase is political/legal. It is often the case (and almost invariably was in the past) that anything to be treated as evidence must be formally read out in the meeting/hearing/, partly to allow it to be challenged and partly so that it is included in the verbatim record. Where a long document is not disputed, it is only sensible to direct that it be *taken as [having been] read*. and a note about where to find it inserted in the minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a chance the meaning is vaguely theological.  Acceptance of scripture "as read", e.g., rather than as subjected to the scrutiny of sometimes torturous hermeneutic....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).